# Filtering a `data.table` with bang-bang (`!!`) (expression `call`)

Tags: r, data.table

Given an expression string in R, such as `Species == 'setosa' & Petal.Length > 1.5`, you can pass that expression through to a filter statement using `!!` in `dplyr`.

```
exp_string = rlang::parse_expr("Species == 'setosa' & `Petal.Length` > 1.5")
filtered_data <- iris |> filter(!!exp_string)
```

But when translating that to `data.table`, the filtering fails, complaining in a number of ways.

```
iris_dt <- setDT(copy(iris))
iris_dt[exp_string] # i has evaluated to type language
iris_dt[!!exp_string] # invalid argument type
```

So, what is the proper way to pass a filtering statement through to a `data.table` in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `eval` - bang bang (`!!`) works only in the tidyverse environment, in all other cases, it is double negate (`!`)

```
iris_dt[eval(exp_string)]
```

-output

```
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
 1:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
 2:          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa
 3:          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3  setosa
 4:          5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2  setosa
 5:          5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5  setosa
 6:          4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2  setosa
 7:          5.0         3.0          1.6         0.2  setosa
 8:          5.0         3.4          1.6         0.4  setosa
 9:          4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2  setosa
10:          4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2  setosa
11:          5.0         3.5          1.6         0.6  setosa
12:          5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4  setosa
13:          5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2  setosa
```